# How can I import sql file in wampserver?

Tags: mysql, import

I need to import database from my old wamp64 folder save in my flash drive into a new wampserver project.
Okay. I have been working on a wampserver and created a database before my system got damaged but before then I saved the wamp64 folder in a flash drive in order to get access to my work and database created should in case my system get a problem.
Now, I need to import from old wamp64 saved in flash drive into a new project and need some help to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: If it is the same eamp server with the same mysql version, you can simply copy the folder

Comment: For future reference, using the EXPORT (backup) in phpMyAdmin will create you a backup that is easy to restore on the same and in many cases other versions of MySQL. Much more useful than a folder copy

Comment: Please answer @nbk question. It is the most relevant piece of information if you want a decent answer